# AEM 6.1/CQ5 --Technical approach to QA to trouble shoot back end servers, LOGS, etc

Tags: aem

I am GK. Currently working as a AEM 6.1 QA for big Telecom customer.I am really enjoying the way AEM stuff happens. As QA, I involved more in testing of Author(backend) like dragdrop of components, edit... and publish(frontend).
Familair with siteadmin, crx/de....

My ask:- Right now my responsibilities are added and asking me 
"to Technical approach to QA to trouble shoot back end servers, LOGS, etc. Java skills to write test cases. SSH."

I need some help where I can learn trouble shoot backend servers....

Appreciate your qucik reply

Go-Getter
GK

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the foundations of AEM:

- [JCR/Java Content Repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java), a "No SQL" hierarchical data store (think of nodes and their paths as Resources)
- [Apache Felix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Felix), an OSGi implementation to permit loading multiple libraries even when they have version conflicts in their dependencies
- [REST/Representational State Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), a software architecture for the web
- [Apache Sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Sling), an implementation marrying REST principles with the JCR

Then you need to know where people make mistakes, because all QA recognizes you "can't test everything" - so you prioritize your testing efforts where issues are more likely to happen OR the risk is too high if issues aren't known.

AEM also provides several log files for tracking or troubleshooting different things.  They have different formats, and your open question is not specific enough to begin to dive into troubleshooting or monitoring.